# session lost after redirect header location in safari and edge (only from webmail)

Tags: php, session, redirect

I send a hyperlink inside a mail, the target is like `https://example.com/category/12345/ch3k5um/`.
The .htaccess navigate the request to `index?cat=category&id=12345&checksum=ch3k5um`
If everything is ok, session will be set

```
$_SESSION = array( 'foo' => 'bar' );
```

And an then redirect to the target
`header ('location: /target/page', true, 302);`
In there is the check `isset($_SESSION['foo'])`.

This works fine from different mail-clients like thunderbird or apple-mail with all browsers. And also from normal login-form.

If i click this link in a webmail like "web.de" or "gmx.net", it goes to their dereferrer, than to the called link,
there the session will be set - and redirect to /target/page -
and here the session is lost, but only with safari and edge..

Comment: if posted just for future reference, you should try to better clarify the problem and post the question on it´s own, and then you may post your solution as an answer. But I believe your question isn't clear: "they're using dereferrer and this does not have the session set, but only on safari and edge!" You should remove your solution from the question and expand upon the problem itself.

Comment: @lucasreta i agree. hope now it's better (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After some hours struggeling i found the solution.**

The Problem of losing the session after redirect with header location,
The *new* "**samesite**" attribute from PHP 7.3.
If this is `Strict`, you will lose the session after `header( 'Location: /foo' , true, 302);`
use `Lax` and fine..

At this moment i dont know why this just happens from webmail and only on safari and edge..

the session_starts at the top of the scripts:

```
$sessionSet = array(
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ],
    'secure' => TRUE,
    'httponly' => TRUE,
    'samesite' => 'Lax',    //  Strict will lose the session for some reason in some case..
    'lifetime' => 18000
);
ini_set( 'session.save_path', '/dir/to/sessions' );
ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime', $sessionSet[ 'lifetime' ] );
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', $sessionSet[ 'lifetime' ] );
ini_set( 'session.gc_probability', 1 );
ini_set( 'session.gc_divisor', 3 );
ini_set( 'session.cookie_samesite', $sessionSet[ 'samesite' ] );
session_set_cookie_params( $sessionSet );
session_start();
```